# How to read a Mongo Document and save it to an object?

Tags: c#, wpf, mongodb

I need to read certain fields in documents from Mongo. I filtered out a document using the `Filter.EQ()` method but how can I find and store a field in that document? This is my code:

```
public void human_radioButton_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Upload human = new Upload(); //opens connection to the database and collection

        var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("name", "Human");
        race_desc description = new race_desc();
        description.desc = Convert.ToString(filter);
        desc_textBox.Text = description.desc;
```

However, this doesn't work since I didn't grab any fields, just the document. So how can I read a field called `'A'` and store it into an object?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you define a filter using the `Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter` here, you merely define a filter that you can use/execute in a query. Much like storing a SQL string in a string variable.

What you missed here is executing the filter and actually retrieve the data. According to [Mongodb C# driver doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/getting-started/csharp/query/#specify-equality-conditions):

```
var collection = _database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("restaurants");
var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("borough", "Manhattan");
var result = await collection.Find(filter).ToListAsync();
```

Then you can iterate the results and access the properties like

```
foreach(var result in results)
{
   //do something here with result.your_property
}
```

And if you just want the first of the result

```
var result = (await collection.Find(filter).ToListAsync()).FirstOrDefault();
```

Now if you want to cast the `BsonDocument` you got now to your own class deserialize document using BsonSerializer:

```
var myObj = BsonSerializer.Deserialize<YourType>(result);
```

You can also map it to your own class:

```
var yourClass = new YourType();
yourClass.Stuff= result["Stuff"].ToString();
```

Comment: Very helpful! Do you know if there's a way to initialize the var file "dynamicaly"? I need to know if there's a way to initiate it on different filters depending on what i get from my call